# Working with Auhtentication and Authorization for imageresizer and IVirtualImageProvider

Tags: asp.net, image-resizing, imageresizer, imageresizer-diskcache

I'm using the http://imageresizing.net/ component to display images on my webapplication.

My problem is that users need to be (forms)authenticated before retreiving an image although I allow anonymous users.

I created my own implementations for VirtualImageProvider and VirtualFile by implementing their Interfaces:

```
    public class CustomVirtualImageProvider : IVirtualImageProvider, IPlugin
{
    public bool FileExists(string virtualPath, NameValueCollection queryString)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public IVirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath, NameValueCollection queryString)
    {
        var customVirtualFile = new CustomVirtualFile(virtualPath, queryString);

        return customVirtualFile;
    }

    public IPlugin Install(Config c)
    {
        c.Plugins.add_plugin(this);
        return this;
    }

    public bool Uninstall(Config c)
    {
        c.Plugins.remove_plugin(this);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and

```
    public class CustomVirtualFile : IVirtualFile
{
    private readonly string _virtualPath;

    public CustomVirtualFile(string virtualPath, NameValueCollection query)
    {
        _virtualPath = virtualPath;
        this.query = new ResizeSettings(query);
    }

    protected ResizeSettings query;

    public System.IO.Stream Open()
    {
        var pathService = new ICustomImagePathService();

        string path = pathService.GetPhysicalPathByVirtual(_virtualPath);

        var fi = new FileInfo(path);
        if (!fi.Exists)
        {
            return null;
        }

        CurrentLogger.Logger.Debug("Processing: " + _virtualPath);

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var bytes = new byte[file.Length];
            file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
            ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
        }

        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return ms;
    }

    public string VirtualPath { get { return _virtualPath; } }
}
```

In the web.config I've setup the DiskCache plugin:

```
<diskcache dir="/ImageCache" />
```

This /ImageCache is a VirtualDirectory within IIS.

I'm using asp.net FormsAuthentication.

The requirement is users need to be authenticated when getting images from:
**https://myhost/i/userprofile/(guid)**.

Un-authenticated users/requests are allowed to get images from:
**https://myhost/i/public/logos/(guid)**.

To achieve this, I created these folders in my webapplication:

- /i
- /i/public

In these folders I've added a test default.aspx page and these web.config's:

**/i**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
     <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**/i/public**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Testing with the webpages works:

/i/default.aspx  --> redirects to login page. Good.

/i/public/default.aspx --> shows the page. Good.

/i/userprofile/d39a2fe0-2f1d-9750-e8d4-ebbe0f87d790.jpg?w=50&h=50  --> redirect to login page. Good.

/i/public/applogo/297/3347df8d-ef47-4280-ac2d-75a740b5898e.jpg?w=100&h=100 --> redirect to login page. **Not good**.

Can some one help me with this issue? I want this last image to be shown to unauthenticated users.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm now figuring out if perhaps MVC-routing is causing this issue

Comment: Adding this "routes.IgnoreRoute("i/{*pathInfo}");" didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working by making the following changes:

1) Changing the Anonymous Authentication Credentials (within IIS) from IUSR to the Application Pool Identity

2) Setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests back to "true". During testing I tried disabling it.

All by using ASP.NET Url Authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be using URL Authorization incorrectly here. I think "?" means any authenticated user, but "*" means all users, including those unauthenticated.

You may also need to use `<location>` elements to ensure your configuration is specific to certain URLs.

Have you considered using IIS URL Authorization instead of ASP.NET URL Authorization? 
https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/understanding-iis-url-authorization

Comment: I tried both "?" and "*" for the ALLOW tag, but makes no difference. As I mentioned above, the *.aspx pages both respond correctly to the <authorization> tags. I'm now going to read myself into the IIS Url Authorization. Thank you for that link